# Understanding client and server side validation using data annotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations

I'm using MVC 2.  I have a question regarding client and server side validation.  Lets say I have a class, and it has 3 properties as such:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
public object Property1 { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
public object Property2 { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
public object Property3 { get; set; }
```

On my view I ONLY have Property1 and Property 2 and make them textboxes.  I did not add Property3 to the view (but it is marked as required as above).  If I don't type anything into the textboxes then the client side validation will fail.  If I insert text into the textboxes, will client side pass even though Property3 was not set with a value?  Will it then fail on the server side?

The issue that I am having is on the server side after I clicked the submit button.  Here is my code for my Create action:

```
public ActionResult CreateApplication(Application application)
{
   try
   {
      application.ApplicationStateID = 1;
      application.SubmitterEmployeeNumber = "123456";

      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
         // Code here
      }
   }
   catch
   {
   }
}
```

ApplicationStateID and SubmitterEmployeeNumber is not set on client side (they are both marked as required), so I set it here.  After I set them, why would validation still fail on the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client side validation will pass because there's no corresponding input element to validate, server side validation will fail because you enforce a field to be required and this field value is not posted to the server. You could read [this blog post](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/input-validation-vs-model-validation-in-aspnet-mvc.html) to understand how model validation works and the differences between Input Validation vs Model Validation.

Comment: Thanks.  See my updated question, maybe you can shed some more light. I will go and read that post now.

Comment: The reason for this is because validation is performed during the model binding. You are setting the required properties **after** this model binding occurs. One possible workaround is to use the `TryUpdateModel` method instead of passing it as action argument.

Comment: Thanks for this Darin.  Just a final question, am I doing this correct by puting everything into a try and catch?  Normally in web forms I will check if the application is null like if (application == null).

Comment: You don't need `try/catch` here especially if you are using `TryUpdateModel`. You could use `try/catch` inside the `IsValid` condition because this is where you will perform sensitive operations like trying to update database, etc...

Comment: So I can assume that there will be an application object passed through and it will not be null?  I just don't want to try and set a property value like ApplicationStateID outside the try catch when application might passed through as null.  Can it ever be passed through as null?